What is the correct blender to unity texture/material export work flow?
I have modeled and textured a building in Blender by following a tutorial from BlenderGuru.
Can any one please help me with exporting those textures into unity. I have used 4 textures in my building and have used 1 mask texture. The mask textures rgb value controls three other textures that appear on the building.
Q: Do I have to create a custom shader in unity to achieve a similar look like blender? What is the proper work flow for this?
Link:
How to make an abandoned house in Blender - Tutorial
Thanks!

Assume that a reader will not click any external links. If you want to ask "how to make a material like the one in this tutorial in Unity", then you'll need to edit your question to give a complete description of the material you want to make. Be sure to also mention what render pipeline you're using in Unity (built-in, URP, or HDRP).

I believe that advanced shader / shader graph effects in blender do not carry over to Unity. Perhaps you can "apply" the mask before exporting, so it becomes just a single imagetexture.

Thanks Kevin!
I ended up creating my own shader graph to solve this issue.
I already had the diffuse,normals and roughness maps of the individual shaders.
So I created a sub shader which combines all those textures as show below.

After that I used 3 of those to display 3 textures as I had done in blender.
And then used the mask texture image exported along with and sample gradient to blend two of those textures as shown below.

I then used the same output and combined it with another texture using same setup and blend node.
This gave me a result which was similar to what I had in blender. The shader can be further fine tuned by adjusting the gradient to get better masking.


If you want to recreate the material from the video, with all of its settings, in Unity, you will need to create a custom shader. The workflow for this will depend on which Render Pipeline you are using (built-in, URP, or HDRP). In brief, if you are using the built-in Render Pipline, you'll need to write an HLSL shader or use a third-party plugin such as Amplify. If you are using URP or HDRP, you would instead use the Shader Graph. Amplify and Shader Graph are node-based graph editors somewhat similar to the node-based material editor in Blender.
However, the material graph shown in that Blender tutorial video looks fairly complex:

Materials in Blender often are not optimized for real-time performance, since Blender is typically used to pre-render images and videos. You would probably be better off baking this material into several textures that work with the standard PBR shaders in Unity.
Baking is complicated and the steps change over time with different versions of Blender. Rather than try to get into the specifics here, I will just recommend that you look up baking tutorials for the specific version of Blender that you are using. As far as what to bake, typically at minimum you want to bake the following:

Albedo texture
Metallic or smoothness map
Normal map

Depending on how you want to balance visual quality vs. performance, you might also want to bake out an Ambient Map or Detail Maps. Note that HDRP and URP use Channel Packing to combine multiple maps into one four-channel texture for better performance. I typically bake each map separately and combine them into a Channel Packed texture in Photoshop.
Note: I did not watch the 25-minute video; I just skimmed it to find the material graph.
